# Disable ad-hoc and development distribution exports in Xcode Cloud

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, continuous-integration, xcode-cloud

I am using Xcode Cloud to archive a mobile application and everything works well. But it is a large project so I am trying to optimize the overall build time. When I examine logs I can see that Xcode Cloud is exporting the archive for development, ad-hoc and app-store distribution. The exports for ad-hoc and development distribution take a substantial amount of time and I don't need them at all. I was trying to research if there is a way to disable these exports but I was not able to find anything. Does anybody know about a way to disable them? Thank you for any help.

Comment: unfortunately nope

Answer (score -1):

Select manage workflows. There, you can disable workflow. (Xcode 15)

[image: Report navigator Xcode cloud workflow option]